# Is it possible to return a tuple with value in the dictionary by input key?

Tags: c++

{i:1, j:2, k:3} return (1,2,3) How can you do this?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

```
 dictionary = {'A':True, 'B':False, 'C':True, 'D':False} 
 my_list = [key for key in dictionary.keys() if dictionary[key]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dict_ = {'A':True, 'B':False, 'C':True, 'D':False} 
keys = [key for key, value in dict_.items() if value]
```

Answer (score 0):

By this list compression, you can get the specific keys which value is true

```
[i for i,j in a.items() if j]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension like this:

```
D = {'A':True, 'B':False, 'C':True, 'D':False}

L = [k for k in D if D[k]] # ['A', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the data

```
my_dictionary = {'A':True, 'B':False, 'C':True, 'D':False}
```

Now go through the dictionary and add it to the list if the dictionary key is True

```
my_list = [i for i in my_dictionary if my_dictionary[i]]
```

Which gives

```
['A', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use [filter](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/filter) -

```
D = {'A':True, 'B':False, 'C':True, 'D':False}

>>> list(filter(lambda x: D[x],D))
['A', 'C']
```